# VSTO: Cached exchange mode VS LastModificationTime

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am developing a VSTO Outlook Add-In that is relying on the LastModificationTime property of Outlook Appointment. The problem is when Cached exchange mode is turned On, the LastModificationTime property auto updates each time I close Outlook. Is there possible solution I can use to get the date and time when user changed the appointment, instead of date and time when cached exchange mode changed the appointment?

Seeing that there are not a lot of responses I wanted to describe my problem in more detail - this is what happens:

1. I change an item (the abnormal behavior happens only to items I've changed)
2. LastModificationTime is changed to the time when I've saved the item (I see the change with OutlookSpy). (eg. LastModificationTime  3:30:00 PM)
3. I work until 4:00:00 PM and check the LastModificationTime and it still shows 3:30:00 PM
4. I close outlook
5. I open outlook and check LastModificationTime. Now the LastModificationTime shows 3:30:42 instead of 3:30:00.
   Why did it add extra 42 seconds after I had reopened the Outlook?

Thank you for any suggestions you can give me.

Comment: mmb i dont get this ... do you have anything else running in outlook.

Comment: 76mel, I also don't get it, that why I ask the question. I have few more addIns running in Outlook and I tried disabling all of them, but it changed nothing.

Comment: I've added more explanations regarding nature of my problem in the description at the top.

Comment: Victor F, I dont see this behavior but our env may be different etc. Do you get the same behavior when you dont run your addin ?

Comment: Also I think that the time the 3:30:42 is the real time that the item is saved to exchange as it's timestamp the server applied .. the clients (cached) time stamp is transiant. So what are you doing with the LastModificationTime as there may be another way ?

Comment: I use it for synchronization.
P.S. Thank you for your help, I was able to find a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find two workarounds for my problem, #1 being unacceptable for me and #2 I actually used:

Solution #1: Use registry entries to disable exchange server on add-in shutdown and re-enable it on add-in startup. Below is sample code:

```
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Try
        Dim regTopKey As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
        Dim regPath As String = "\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a"
        Dim oldValue As Byte() = Registry.GetValue(regTopKey & regPath, "00036601_Backup", Nothing)
        If oldValue IsNot Nothing Then
            Registry.SetValue(regTopKey & regPath, "00036601", oldValue, RegistryValueKind.Binary)
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
    Try
        Dim disableExchangeMode As Byte() = {4, 0, 0, 0}
        Dim regTopKey As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
        Dim regPath As String = "\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a"
        Dim currentValue As Byte() = Registry.GetValue(regTopKey & regPath, "00036601", Nothing)
        If currentValue IsNot Nothing Then
            Registry.SetValue(regTopKey & regPath, "00036601_Backup", currentValue, RegistryValueKind.Binary)
        End If
        Registry.SetValue(regTopKey & regPath, "00036601", disableExchangeMode, RegistryValueKind.Binary)
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Solution #2: Detect when user changes an appointment item and save the change in user defined property field. Below is sample code:

```
Private Sub appointmentSave(ByVal Item As Object) Handles _m_olAppointment.ItemChange, _m_olAppointment.ItemAdd
    Try
        Dim dateNow As Date = Date.Now
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.AppointmentItem Then
            If (dateNow - _lastFolderSwitch).TotalMilliseconds > 500 Then
                _lastFolderSwitch = dateNow
                Dim appointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = CType(Item, Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                If (dateNow - appointmentItem.LastModificationTime).TotalMilliseconds < 100 Then
                    Dim lastModifiedDate As Outlook.UserProperty = appointmentItem.UserProperties.Add("lastModifiedDate", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, True)
                    lastModifiedDate.Value = dateNow.ToString
                    appointmentItem.Save()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Thank You everybody that helped